# Match all occurences with a single or regex

Tags: regex

I need to find regex which matches both:

```
;hostname:MytestHello;

;message:#Hellowtestworld;
```

In this value:

```
;hostname:MytestHello;severity:major;message:#Hellowtestworld;
```

Here is my regex shot:

```
(hostname:|message:).*?(test).*?\;
```

But I only get the first occurence:

```
hostname:nimsofttest22;
```

What can I do in order to get **BOTH** results ?

Comment: [You already match both](https://regex101.com/r/DmLcZ8/1) with your regex pattern. Are you using JavaScript and forogt to use `g` modifier? Or use `re.search` instead of `re.finditer` in Python? BTW, if your input is different, you may not get the same results. You'd better use something like [`(?:hostname:|message:)[^;]*?test[^;]*;`](https://regex101.com/r/DmLcZ8/2). And if you need that `;` in front, add `;?` at the start of the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i'm using regex101 website

Comment: now I get that I need to change to global. thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the multiple matching part is easy to solve with a global modifier or the correct language function/method that returns multiple matches, your pattern contains a flaw: it may return unwanted results if `message` or `hostname` with no `test` after them appear before another occurrence with `test`. See [this regex demo to understand what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/DmLcZ8/3).

So, the correct way is to restrict `.` here, to match any char but `;` (that acts as a delimiter in your string):

```
/(?:hostname|message):[^;]*?test[^;]*;/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmLcZ8/5).

Note: you should adapt the pattern for any language method//function that you will choose later in the code.

**Details**

- `(?:hostname|message)` - either of the 2 substrings
- `:` - a colon
- `[^;]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `;`, as *few* as possible
- `test` - `test`
- `[^;]*` - any 0+ chars other than `;` as many as possible
- `;` - a semi-colon.